# What does this param expansion do?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

What exactly does the following do?

```
MY_VAR=${MY_INPUT##*$'\n'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deletes the longest match of the substring `*\n` from the start of the string stored in `MY_INPUT`. Note that `*` is a wildcard, so the result is that every line of `MY_INPUT` is discarded except the last one, which is stored in `MY_VAR`. The `$` before `'\n'` is put there just to evaluate `\n` and consider it as a newline instead of literally the characters `\` and `n`.

Some examples:

```
MY_INPUT            MY_VAR
"a\nb\nc"        -> "c"
"a\n"            -> ""
"abcde\n\n\ndef" -> "def"
```

Note: in the second example the last line is empty so `MY_VAR` is an empty string.

---

As requested, another way to do this could be:

```
tail -n1 <<< "$MY_INPUT"
```

or:

```
echo "$MY_INPUT" | tail -n1
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input/output?

Comment: @Jim `MY_INPUT=$( printf 'line1\nline2\nline3' ); MY_VAR=${MY_INPUT##*$'\n'}; echo "$MY_VAR"` will output `line3`. It's basically doing `tail -n 1` on the contents of `$MY_INPUT`.

Comment: @Jim Added some examples!

Comment: Is there a more readable way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Jim added this too!

Comment: One more thing. Why is the `\n` in single quotes? Does it need to be for some reason?

Comment: @Jim yes, it needs to be in quotes to be parsed by `$`.

Comment: What do you mean by parsed by '$'? That is the regex for marking the end of line right?

Comment: @Jim No. It's not a regexp. `$` is used to evaluate `\n` as a newline and not two characters (`\` and `n`). Since that `$` is a bash operator it needs to know when to start and when to stop evaluating, thus you need to add quotes around what you want to evaluate. This means that if you want to evaluate `\n` you'll have to do `$'\n'`, and if you want to evaluate `\t\r\n` you'll have to do `$'\t\r\n'`.

Comment: Because of a typo in your answer the highligting is not correct and I am not sure I get what you mean. Could you please correct that? Also what is it that `$` operator does exactly? How does it work?

Comment: @Jim man, if you want to ask another question go ahead and make another post, I can't be answering 999 extra questions in the comment section, sorry.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Yes you are right. Could you please at least fix the code snippet highlight in your previous comment? I can't edit it

Comment: @Jim comments can't be edited, sorry. Anyway it's pretty clear that I wanted to highlight the dollar sign and not the word "test".